# Sql Server - 2 queries executed together takes longer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 queries.

Query # 1: inserts some data into a temp table

Query # 2: inserts the data from the temp table (with some joins) into a new table.

Running Query #1 alone takes 3 seconds. Running Query #2 alone takes 12 seconds.

When I run them both together as one execution, it runs forever (over 4 minutes).

What could possibly be the reason for this?

(I would post my code but it's *very* long and not much understandable to the outsider.)

Here's my SQL (at your own risk): Remember they run fine when ran alone.

```
-- START QUERY #1
SELECT * INTO #TempProdForSiteGoingTrim
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            p.idProduct
            , p.active
            , p.sku
            , p.description
            , p.listprice
            , p.price
            , p.imageurl
            , p.smallimageurl
            , p.idManufacturer
            , sortOrder 
            , CASE WHEN p.pgroup = '' OR p.pgroup IS NULL THEN CAST(p.idProduct AS VARCHAR) ELSE pgroup END [pgroup]
            , CASE WHEN pa2.attr IS NULL  THEN CAST(p.idProduct AS VARCHAR) ELSE CASE WHEN p.pgroup = '' OR p.pgroup IS NULL THEN CAST(p.idProduct AS VARCHAR) ELSE pgroup END END [RugGroup] 
            , pa1.attr [Color]
            , pa3.attr [Collection]
            , pa2.attr [RugSize]
            , pa4.attr[RugShape]
        FROM
            (SELECT DISTINCT idProduct  FROM ProdSite WHERE idSite = 39 ) s 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM products p  WHERE active = -1 ) p ON s.idproduct = p.idproduct 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t.idproduct, attr FROM  (SELECT max(idprodattr) [idprodattr], idproduct, b.idattrset  FROM productattr a JOIN product_attr b on a.idattr = b.idattr WHERE idattrset = 1 GROUP BY a.idproduct, b.idattrset )t JOIN productattr a ON t.idprodattr = a.idprodattr JOIN product_attr b ON a.idattr = b.idattr) pa1 ON p.idproduct = pa1.idproduct  
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT t.idproduct, attr FROM  (SELECT max(idprodattr)[idprodattr], idproduct, b.idattrset  FROM productattr a JOIN product_attr b on a.idattr = b.idattr WHERE idattrset = 160 GROUP BY a.idproduct, b.idattrset )t JOIN productattr a ON t.idprodattr = a.idprodattr JOIN product_attr b ON a.idattr = b.idattr) pa2 ON p.idproduct = pa2.idproduct  
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t.idproduct, attr FROM  (SELECT max(idprodattr)[idprodattr], idproduct, b.idattrset  FROM productattr a JOIN product_attr b on a.idattr = b.idattr WHERE idattrset = 6  GROUP BY a.idproduct, b.idattrset )t JOIN productattr a ON t.idprodattr = a.idprodattr JOIN product_attr b ON a.idattr = b.idattr) pa3 ON p.idproduct = pa3.idproduct 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t.idproduct, attr FROM  (SELECT max(idprodattr)[idprodattr], idproduct, b.idattrset  FROM productattr a JOIN product_attr b on a.idattr = b.idattr WHERE idattrset = 62  GROUP BY a.idproduct, b.idattrset )t JOIN productattr a ON t.idprodattr = a.idprodattr JOIN product_attr b ON a.idattr = b.idattr) pa4 ON p.idproduct = pa4.idproduct 
    )t 
 -- END QUERY #1

-- START QUERY #2
DECLARE @listRugSizes TABLE (idmanufacturer int, RugGroup VARCHAR(500), RugSizes VARCHAR(1000))  
INSERT INTO @listRugSizes 
SELECT
    t1.idmanufacturer
    , t1.RugGroup 
    , STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + RugSize FROM  #TempProdForSiteGoingTrim t2 WHERE t2.RugGroup = t1.RugGroup and t2.idmanufacturer = t1.idmanufacturer FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') [Values] 
FROM 
    #TempProdForSiteGoingTrim t1
GROUP BY
    t1.RugGroup 
    , t1.idmanufacturer


INSERT INTO [NewTableForSiteGoingTrim]
SELECT
    p.idProduct
    , p.sku
    , p.description
    , p.listPrice
    , p.price
    , p.imageUrl
    , p.smallImageUrl
    , p.sortOrder
    , p.idManufacturer
    , p.pgroup 
    , p.ruggroup  
    , c.idCategory
    , c.idCategory [fidcategory]
    , c.idParentCategory
    , c.idParentCategory [gidcategory]
    , pc.idParentCategory [hidCategory]  
    , ppc.idParentCategory [iidCategory]
    , m.Name 
    , rp.rewrite_key [rewrite_index]
    , rm.rewrite_key [rewrite_key] 
    , color [Color]
    , collection [Collection]
    , rugsize [RugSize] 
    , ruggroup.rugcount
    , ruggroup.maxprice
    , ruggroup.minprice
    , rs.RugSizes 
    , p.rugshape  
FROM
    #TempProdForSiteGoingTrim p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  ( 
                        SELECT
                            MIN(c.idCategory) [idCategory]
                            , c.idProduct
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    cp.idProduct
                                    , cp.idCategory
                                FROM
                                    dbo.categories_products cp 
                                    JOIN categories c ON cp.idcategory = c.idCategory
                                WHERE
                                    c.idSite = 24  
                            ) c
                        GROUP BY
                            c.idProduct 
                    ) cp ON p.idProduct = cp.idProduct 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories c ON cp.idCategory = c.idCategory  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories pc ON c.idParentCategory = pc.idCategory 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories ppc ON pc.idParentCategory = ppc.idCategory 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN manufacturer m ON p.idManufacturer = m.idManufacturer  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM rewrite WHERE type = 3) rm ON p.idManufacturer = rm.id   
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM rewrite WHERE type = 1) rp ON p.idProduct = rp.id  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @listRugSizes rs ON p.RugGroup = rs.RugGroup and p.idmanufacturer = rs.idmanufacturer
    LEFT OUTER  JOIN
        ( 
                SELECT
                    p.ruggroup 
                    , p.idmanufacturer
                    , min(price) [minPrice] 
                    , count(*) [RugCount] 
                    , m.maxprice
                FROM 
                    #TempProdForSiteGoingTrim p  
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        (
                            SELECT
                                r.ruggroup
                                , r.idmanufacturer
                                , max(price) [maxprice]
                            FROM
                                #TempProdForSiteGoingTrim r
                            WHERE
                                r.idproduct = (SELECT MAX(idproduct) FROM #TempProdForSiteGoingTrim WHERE ruggroup = r.ruggroup AND price = r.price and idmanufacturer = r.idmanufacturer) 
                            GROUP BY
                                ruggroup 
                                , idmanufacturer
                        ) m ON p.ruggroup = m.ruggroup and p.idmanufacturer = m.idmanufacturer
                GROUP BY
                    p.ruggroup 
                    , m.maxprice 
                    , p.idmanufacturer

        ) ruggroup ON p.ruggroup = ruggroup.ruggroup  and p.idmanufacturer = ruggroup.idmanufacturer
-- END QUERY #2
```

**Edit**

When I change the last join "ruggroup" to only group and join by column "ruggroup" and not "ruggroup" and "idmanufacturer" then it works fine.

Comment: Posting your code would be incredibly helpful.  It is very difficult to speculate without seeing any code.

Comment: You said "(with some joins)", without seeing the statements this would be my first guess at the problem.

Comment: @pm_2 very possibly - I did change the last "ruggroup" join which is when I think I started seeing this problem.

Comment: the table variable @listRugSizes can cause this problem if have large amount of data in... try change it for a temp variable.. or write this select that is filling the variable.. in your query instead using the variable.. table variables dont have indexes neither statistics... you should try to set indexes or statistics on your temporary table to see if achieve better performance or if the bigger cost on insert would be too big...